# How to pass only required variable value and get other values as default in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

Here I want to pass only specific variable value and should get other values as default but I am not getting that...

Ex: I want to pass only word2 variable value and want to get word1 value as default Like "Hello See"

```
  *** Keywords ***
  Check order
      [Arguments]    ${word1}=Hello    ${word2}=World
      log to console    word1 is : ${word1}
      log to console    word2 is : ${word2}

  *** Test Cases ***
  Test case 1
      Check order   ${word2}=See


  Test case 1                                                           | FAIL |
  Variable '${word2}' not found.
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is to use only the variable name to the left of the equals:

```
Check order  word2=see
```

This is from the robot framework user guide, in a section titled [Named arguments](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#named-arguments)

> When the named argument syntax is used with user keywords, the argument names must be given without the ${} decoration. For example, user keyword with arguments ${arg1}=first, ${arg2}=second must be used like arg2=override.